# still collects numbers until get a single number

Tags: javascript, string

I want to create a program using `Javascript` that converts an alphabet of a string to an `ASCII` code and collects those numbers until getting a single digit number.

**For example:**
We have this string "Youssef". If we sum their `ASCII` code we get `782`.
We must do this operation now,

```
7 + 8 + 2 = 17 => 1 + 7 => 8 // Now the program will stop.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello *Youssef* welcome to StackOverflow and to the world of Programming and JavaScript as well, please attempt you assignment first on your own, do some research then if you get stuck with your code comeback for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code gives you an idea of how to deal with spreads and implicit casting in order to help you get to the result.

```
const str = "Youssef"

let totASCII = [0]

for (let char of str){
    totASCII[0] += char.charCodeAt(0)
}
totASCII = [...totASCII+""]

while (totASCII.length > 1){
    let intermediate = 0
    totASCII.forEach(item => intermediate += parseInt(item))
    totASCII = [...intermediate+""]
}

console.log(totASCII+"")
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Here at SO code only answers are **not considered good answers**, though, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and may even be removed..